# Use grouped summary to operate in another data.frame column by factor

Tags: r, dplyr, r-factor

I want to compute a `summary` of a grouped `data.frame`, for example.

```
df_summ = mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>% summarise(mean_mpg=mean(mpg))

     am mean_mpg
  (dbl)    (dbl)
1     0 17.14737
2     1 24.39231
```

In order to later transform another `data.frame` that shares the same factor levels, but not the number of rows. For example, calculating the absolute difference from each group's mean of the single values.

Here's the toy example

```
toy=data.frame(am=c(1,1,0,0),mpg=c(1,2,3,4))
```

The calculation I would like to do would be `y = abs(toy$mpg- df_summ$mean_mpg)` by factor.

My head tells me dplyr must be able to do this but I can't come up with a way.
I want to keep the original data.frame (as in, using `mtcars %>% group_by(am) %>% mutate(...)` )

The expected output looks like that

```
toy
  am mpg expected
1  1     1 23.39231
2  1     2 22.39231
3  0     3 14.14737
4  0     4 13.14737
```

Comment: instead of `summarise` which drops all other columns, use `mutate`, which will add the `mean_mpg` column to the existing data frame.

Comment: I'm sorry I phrased my question wrong, let me edit!

Comment: sample data and an example of expected output would be nice.

Comment: @zacdav edited :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the two data frames and then perform the calculation:

```
toy %>% 
    left_join(df_summ) %>% 
    mutate(y = abs(mpg - mean_mpg))
```

giving:

```
Joining, by = "am"
  am mpg mean_mpg        y
1  1   1 24.39231 23.39231
2  1   2 24.39231 22.39231
3  0   3 17.14737 14.14737
4  0   4 17.14737 13.14737
```

Comment: Always trying to keep dfs separate, never thought about joining them. Thank you for the approach, I just need to change names to make sure the left_join uses the correct factors (I actually have more than one factor and my variables I want to operate currently have the same name) but your approach was key